# "Skip" review fails if daily review cap hit

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I sometimes have a review queue open in more than one browser tab.

If I hit the daily review cap for that queue in one tab, selecting `Skip` for a review in another tab (with the intent of "return this review to the queue, I cannot review it now") leads to

> An error occurred when reviewing this item. Please try again.

Sometimes the UI gets stuck in the "loading next item..." mode, sometimes the review buttons are still available.

This used to work differently, with Skip just leading to the usual thank you message:

> Thank you for reviewing `<n>` `<review queue>` today; come back in `<time>` to continue reviewing.

I know this isn't a big deal - I can just close the tab and someone else will eventually review the item. However,

- There shouldn't be an error in the first place.
- The error message is misleading in this case as trying again is not helpful: either it's not possible (review buttons are gone) or it will just lead to the same error.

Comment: This does sound like a regression.

Comment: I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was in fact a regression, introduced while we added more validation to the route that handles review completion requests.

The fix will be out in build rev `2013.11.27.1685` on meta and `2013.11.27.1180` on sites.

Comment: Thanks, checked on 2013.11.28.1180 and there's no error message anymore.